# error: too many arguments for method apply creating a Tree

Tags: scala, tree, arguments

I'm solving [the 99 Scala problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/), but I have a problem with the data type that the author defined for the binary tree representation:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
  override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}
case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
  override def toString = "."
}
object Node {
  def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
}
```

I get this error:

```
scala> :load tree.scala
Loading tree.scala...
defined class Tree
defined class Node
defined object End
<console>:16: error: too many arguments for method apply: (value: T)Node[T] in object Node
       def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
```

But a friend that sits next to me with the same OS (ubuntu 14.04) and the same version of Scala (2.11.8) doesn't get those errors and his code, that is the same, is working fine.

I'm very new to Scala, but this seems very weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = new Node(value, End, End)
//                                ^^^
```

to call the constructor, not the `apply` again (whose signature doesn't match with three arguments).

Comment: Now it compiles fine. Tomorrow I will test it doing real things with the class. Thanks.